# Enlarge a GeoJSON polygon

Tags: javascript, geometry, polygon, geojson

*How to enlarge a GeoJSON polygon ?*

Say I have a GeoJSON polygon

[image: small polygon]

I'd like to enlarge this shape to have a larger polygon with the same basis

[image]

I did not found anything on the web about this. I found many promising libraries such as **turf.js**, but couldn't figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to **[turf.js](http://turfjs.org/)**.

A combination of `turf.buffer()` and `turf.simplify()` does the trick.

[Reference](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/507)